# Html e-mail table cells vertically center themselves in outlook

Tags: html, css, email, outlook

Welp, in my previous question, i was a table noob(probably still am) so i've learned to code table by hand and my html e-mail mostly looks fine now but in litmus tests, my footer appears weird. Some elements vertically align themselves to the middle.

```
<head></head>
```

Here is the js fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/zr00qgdr/ It's fine here. but if you go to litmus tests here: https://litmus.com/pub/533fe66/screenshots You'll see that bottom elements are messed up in outlook 2007/10/13. (I know they are images. But that's all i can do. Text is sadly not a choice...)

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The fact is that Outlook uses Word for rendering HTML markup (message bodies).

It may not answer the question, but I hope you'll find the following series of articles helpful:

- [Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook 2007 (Part 1 of 2)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338201(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook 2007 (Part 2 of 2)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338200(v=office.12).aspx)